# How can I find all Clang versions installed on my Mac?

Tags: macos, clang

```
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

which clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

I'm on Mac, 10.13.6, any instructions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `which -a clang` to list all of the `clang`s on your `PATH`. Ones which aren't on your `PATH`, like if you've installed Clang somewhere out of the ordinary, won't be shown.

A complication is that `/usr/bin/clang` is actually a trampoline that launches the `clang` within the currently active developer dir, selected by `xcode-select` or the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable. So, knowing that `/usr/bin/clang` is there doesn't tell you either which one it will bounce to or which other versions could be activated. `xcrun -f clang` will tell the first (which will be bounced to). To my knowledge, there's no way to get Apple's tools to list out the possible developer dirs. So, if you have multiple versions of Xcode (or the Command Line Tools) installed, `which -a clang` won't see them.

A more reliable way would be to search the file system. You could use `find / -type f -perm +a+x -name clang`, but that will be slow. The other thing you can try is Spotlight, but I find that the internals of Xcode app bundles are not indexed.

Comment: I did `which -a clang`, and output is `/usr/bin/clang`, and your explanation is very thorough and makes total sense, thanks!